# Commutative algebra with a geometric flavor

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Does anybody know where can I find a book with topics similar to the ones in Atiyah's Introduction to commutative algebra, but with some sort of geometric motivation? Thanks!

Comment: A standard reference with a slight geometric flavor is Lang's [treatise](http://spikedmath.com/comics/Lang-Eggnog-Recipe-1.pdf) on the matter.

Comment: Could you say more about what your goals are?

Comment: Atiyah's book has a lot of geometrical motivation if you go through the exercises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try David Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*. It is lengthy, but he definitely ties things to algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it. I've read your Differential geometry notes, by the way; they're awesome. :)